# Не понятен вывод функции printf() в Си

Tags: c

В Си:

```
int ctr = 0;
while(ctr < MAX)
  printf("[%d] - %d\n", ctr, array[ctr++]);
```

printf начинает выводить `[1]` -, почему с 1, а не с 0? Ведь `ctr = 0`, и до `ctr++` еще не дошло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Alex Krass](/users/16416/alex-krass), в общем случае Вы, безусловно, правы.

--

Если же речь идет о **cdecl** функции и **x86 архитектуре**, то в [вике](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) написано, что

```
 function arguments are pushed on the stack in the reverse order.
```

Таким образом, сначала вычисляется последний аргумент `printf()` (т.е. `array[ctr++]`) и его значение отправляется в стек (и именно в  ходе этого вычисления происходит инкремент переменной `ctr`), а затем в стек отправится текущее (к этому моменту) значение `ctr`, последним в стек попадет адрес строки с форматом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Посоветуйте где можно подробнее об этом и других подобных вещах почитать (тонкости языка Си, архитектуры компьютера). Желательно на русском.

Comment: @dr_kraken, к сожалению, не могу сходу ничего вспомнить.

--

Хороший инструмент для изучения тонкостей -- это самостоятельное экспериментирование вместе с анализом ассемблерного кода, который делает компилятор

(например, в результате `gcc -S test.c`),

последующее "гугление" для верификации собственных гипотез 

(правда, лучше спрашивать на английском (попутно найдете кучу ссылок (по большей части бесполезных) по архитектуре компьютеров.))

и размышления на тему "а как бы я сам это компилировал".

--

Если еще не читали K&R, то обязательно прочтите.

Answer (score 4):

Ваш код неверен, он содержит [undefined behaviour](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior) (UB).

Согласно стандарту, вы не имеете права читать или писать в одну и ту же переменную между двумя последовательными sequence point'ами. Ваш код, однако, считывает `x` дважды и модифицирует один раз. Несмотря на то, что конкретные компиляторы *могут* фиксировать порядок вычисления аргументов, даже с таким порядком UB **недопустимо**.

Имея UB в коде, компилятор **не имеет никаких обязательств** по его работе. Код имеет право вывести и 1, и 2, и «съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок». То, что в данном случае он выводит 1 — случайность.

С таким кодом готовьтесь к сюрпризам и неожиданным вылетам в казалось бы несвязанном коде, особенно при включенной максимальной оптимизации, или при улучшении качества компилятора (компиляторы, которые компилируют код наивно, выражение за выражением, в принципе не могут обеспечить хорошего качества кодогенерации).

Что нужно делать? Просто не пишите код, содержащий UB. Заодно и читать его станет граздо легче. Смотрите, как просто:

```
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < MAX; ctr++)
    printf("[%d] - %d\n", ctr, array[ctr]);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне этот цикл for() известен. Просто я пытался реализовать его через цикл while(). Получился такой вывод. Мне стало интересно, почему. Может посоветуете какую-нибудь литературу по тонкостям языка Си и архитектуре ПК, желательно на русском.

Comment: @dr_kraken: Ох. Насчёт тонкостей C, думаю, вам лучше сможет подсказать @avp, он гуру. Я, честно говоря, учился на примерах, упорно наступая на грабли и прилежно разочаровываясь в своих неверных представлениях о языке. Я бы посоветовал подучить английский и перейти на англоязычную литературу, на текущий момент она в разы обширнее (к сожалению).

Ваш вопрос ясен: код практический одинаковый, почему же ведёт себя по разному? Это — одни из граблей, хорошо, что вы на них наступили в учебном примере, а не в production-коде.

Успехов вам, вы задаёте правильные вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что сначала вычисляются аргументы у функции и только потом они передаются в саму функцию. И если я не ошибаюсь, порядок вычисления никто не гарантирует.

Comment: Что значит никто не гарантирует??? в любом случае, если в компиляторе функцияс аргументом  + написана раньше, чем -, то она будет обрабатываться раньше...

Comment: @cema93: Нет, конечно. Как захочет оптимизатор, так и будет. Гарантировать что-то может только стандарт и документация на конкретный компилятор.

Answer (score 1):

В Си принято при вызове функции вычислять и помещать аргументы в стек в обратном порядке. Это обусловлено тем, что после перехода по адресу их можно доставать в прямом порядке.

В данном случаи для реализации printf (функции с неопределенным числом аргументов) это вообще критически важно, т.к. кол-во передаваемых аргументов хранится только в шаблоне (в виде строки в первом аргументе) и его нужно извлечь из стека первым, чтобы потом по нему понять сколько еще параметров требуется извлечь из стека.

Более подробно как именно происходит вызов функции и почему аргументы ложатся так Вы можете прочитать [6.10 Подпрограммы из Ассемблер в Linux для программистов C](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2_Linux_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_C#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.BC.D1.8B)